# How do you web-scrape past a "show more" button using BeautifulSoup Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup on python to scrape football statistics from this website: https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/2020-21. Yet the site only shows the first 200 games of the season and the rest of the 180 games are behind a "show more" button. The button does not change the url so I can't just replace the url.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

scores_html_text = requests.get('https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/2020-21').text
scores_soup = BeautifulSoup(scores_html_text, 'lxml')

fixtures = scores_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'fixres__item')
```

This only gets the first 200 fixtures.

How would I access the html past the show more button?

Comment: You could try Selenium. chromium driver had headless mode, so you can find button and click it!

Answer (score 3):

The hidden results are inside `<script>` tag, so to get all 380 results you need to parse it additionally:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/2020-21"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

script = soup.select_one('[type="text/show-more"]')
script.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(script.contents[0], "html.parser"))

all_data = []
for item in soup.select(".fixres__item"):
    all_data.append(item.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")[:5])
    all_data[-1].append(
        item.find_previous(class_="fixres__header2").get_text(strip=True)
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data, columns=["Team 1", "Score 1", "Score 2", "Time", "Team 2", "Date"]
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                       Team 1 Score 1 Score 2   Time                    Team 2                     Date
0                     Arsenal       2       0  16:00  Brighton and Hove Albion          Sunday 23rd May
1                 Aston Villa       2       1  16:00                   Chelsea          Sunday 23rd May
2                      Fulham       0       2  16:00          Newcastle United          Sunday 23rd May
3                Leeds United       3       1  16:00      West Bromwich Albion          Sunday 23rd May

...

377            Crystal Palace       1       0  15:00               Southampton  Saturday 12th September
378                 Liverpool       4       3  17:30              Leeds United  Saturday 12th September
379           West Ham United       0       2  20:00          Newcastle United  Saturday 12th September
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of how to do this with BeautifulSoup, but this is how I would do it using Selenium (note that I am very new to Selenium, so there are probably better ways of doing this).

The imports used are:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
```

You will also need to download the [Chrome](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) webdriver (assuming that you are on Chrome), and place it in the same directory as your script, or in your library path.

There will be a cookies popup which you have to workaround:

```
# prepare the driver
URL = "https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/2020-21"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
# wait so that driver has loaded before we look for the cookies popup
time.sleep(2)

# accept cookies popup, which occurs in an iframe
# begin by locating iframe
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('sp_message_iframe_533903')
# find the accept button (inspect element and copy Xpath of button)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/button[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.refresh()

# find "show more text" button and click
driver.find_element_by_class_name("plus-more__text").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried to go up a few levels and this worked , u might need to process it a wee bit more.

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

scores_html_text = requests.get('https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/2020-21').text
scores_soup = BeautifulSoup(scores_html_text,'lxml')

fixtures = scores_soup.find(class_ = 'site-layout-secondary block page-nav__offset grid')
print(fixtures)
```